# When will the data i stored in NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults() change?

Tags: ios, nsuserdefaults

If I download a new version of my app, will it clear all the data I stored in the `NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()`? What will it be if I repeat install and delete my app?
I down a former version of my app from app store. And i install a new version of my app using Xcode. The data saved in NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults() disappeared. Two apps are both release version with a same bundle id. But certificate is different, one is develop, the other is distribution. Is this normal？

Comment: If you upgrade, then it won't change.  If you delete and install then it will be wiped.

Comment: I down a former version of my app from app store. And i install a new version of my app using Xcode. The data saved in NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults() disappeared. Why?

Comment: Ah so you have both a debug and release version of your app on the same device.  Are the bundle id's the same between the two apps?

Comment: @Joe Your comment is your main question , probably you should add the comment in you actual question

Answer (score 1):

If you update your app then it will not change
but if you delete and again install then `NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()` will changed.

Answer (score 1):

When you delete your app, It deletes your apps user defaults. However this may not properly work on ios simulator. When you update your application without deleting it first, user defaults wont be changed. But you can delete user default with some code as well.

```
let appDomain = NSBundle.mainBundle().bundleIdentifier!        
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().removePersistentDomainForName(appDomain)
```

Comment: I down a former version of my app from app store. And i install a new version of my app using Xcode. The data saved in NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults() disappeared. Is this normal？

Comment: Is this on a device or simulator ?This could be due to different reasons. Please check if this behavior repeats. I assume you havent add anything to your new code which removes the previous user defaults ?

Comment: Both on device, same bundle id, both release.